# Yii2 authclient на базе Trello (OAuth1)

Tags: yii2, oauth, trello

Всем привет, нужна помощь.
Реализовываю Trello аутентификацию на базе OAuth1 (https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/oauth.html) с использованием yii2-authclient (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient). Первые два этапа GetRequestToken и AuthorizeToken проходят отлично, но на последнем этапе GetAccessToken вываливает ошибку:

```
Request failed with code: 500, message: Invalid Signature
```

Код, который использую:

```
/**
 * Controller
 */
class TrelloController extends Controller{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $client = new AuthClientTrello();
        $client->setReturnUrl(Url::to(['/auth/trello/verification'], true));
        $request_token = $client->fetchRequestToken();
        $url = $client->buildAuthUrl($request_token);
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    public function actionVerification($oauth_token, $oauth_verifier = '')
    {
        $client = new AuthClientTrello();
        $access_token = $client->fetchAccessToken();
        return $access_token;
    }
}

/**
* AuthClientTrello
*/
class AuthClientTrello extends \yii\authclient\OAuth1{
    public $version = '1.0';
    public $apiBaseUrl = 'https://trello.com/1';
    public $scope = 'read';

    public $consumerKey = 'MY_KEY';
    public $consumerSecret = 'MY_SECRET';

    public $requestTokenUrl = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken';
    public $requestTokenMethod = 'GET';

    public $accessTokenUrl = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken';
    public $accessTokenMethod = 'GET';

    public $authUrl = 'https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function defaultName()
    {
        return 'trello';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function defaultTitle()
    {
        return 'Trello';
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение найдено. После переопределения в моем классе AuthClientTrello двух методов fetchAccessToken и composeSignatureKey, как описано тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/31938164 все заработало